# How to Escape \ backslash character in PowerShell Active Directory filter

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to filter groups in Active Directory that have a UNC in the Info field, but am having great difficulty finding how to escape the backslash character in the UNZ path. The following returns no results:

`Get-ADGroup -filter 'Info -like "*\\server\share*"' -Properties Name,Info | Select Name,Info`

Whereas the following does return some results, but would not be accurate if two groups had similar UNC paths:

`Get-ADGroup -filter 'Info -like "*server*share*"' -Properties Name,Info | Select Name,Info`

I've tried using `\5c`, `\u5c`, `[char]0x25`,  `` `u{5c} ``, `*\\\\server\\path*`, `` *`\`\server`\path* `` all without success, and have run out of ideas and search results to try.

Comment: Have you tried without the wildcard at the beginning? `"\\server\share*"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-LDAPFilter` parameter, then substitute all literal backslashes with the escape sequence `\5C`:

```
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter '(info=*\5C\5Cserver\5Cshare*)'
```

You could write a generic function to take care of escaping string values:

```
function ConvertTo-LDAPFilterString
{
  param(
    [string]$Value
  )

  $charsToEscape = "\*()`0".ToCharArray()

  foreach($char in $charsToEscape){
    $escapeSequence = '\{0:X2}' -f +$char
    $Value = $Value.Replace("$char", $escapeSequence)
  }

  return $Value
}
```

Now you can do:

```
$escapedPath = ConvertTo-LDAPFilterString '\\server\share'
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(info=*$escapedPath*)"
```

---

As to *why* that is, it's not specific to Active Directory, but part of the design of LDAPv3.

[RFC 4515 § 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515#section-3) describes the correct grammar of LDAPv3 filter strings, which includes something called "the value-encoding rule":

> [...] the octets that represent the
> ASCII characters "*" (ASCII 0x2a), "(" (ASCII 0x28), ")" (ASCII
> 0x29), "\" (ASCII 0x5c), and NUL (ASCII 0x00) **are represented as a
> backslash "\" (ASCII 0x5c) followed by the two hexadecimal digits
> representing the value of the encoded octet.**

The reason for this narrow and perculiar encoding rule is to allow *unambiguous* forward-only parsing of filter strings - a `\` in the value part of a clause is *always* the start of a fixed-length escape sequence because a literal `\` would *also* have been encoded as a fixed-width escape sequence :)